# How can I print out words from a 2d array into a grid with even spaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to print out a 2d array of different lengthed words as a grid.

And I'm trying to get the word spacing to be even.

***Note: The words in the array are randomized each time.***

Example,

```
arr = [
   ['eighteen', 'twenty-two', 'twenty-one', 'ten', 'twenty-three'], 
   ['eleven', 'thirteen', 'four', 'three', 'twenty'], 
   ['twenty-eight', 'six', 'fourteen', 'seventeen', 'twenty-seven'], 
   ['twenty-four', 'two', 'nine', 'one', 'five'], 
   ['sixteen', 'fifteen', 'twelve', 'twenty-nine', 'seven']]

for i in range(5):
    x = arr[i]
    y = "    ".join(x)
    print(f"\t\t{y}",end="\t")
    print("\n\n")
```

Output:

```
    eighteen    twenty-two    twenty-one    ten    twenty-three 


    eleven    thirteen    four    three    twenty   


    twenty-eight    six    fourteen    seventeen    twenty-seven    


    twenty-four    two    nine    one    five   


    sixteen    fifteen    twelve    twenty-nine    seven
```

However, I want it to look more like this:

```
   eighteen       twenty-two       twenty-one         ten         twenty-three 


    eleven         thirteen          four            three           twenty   


 twenty-eight        six            fourteen       seventeen      twenty-seven    


  twenty-four        two              nine            one             five   


    sixteen         fifteen          twelve        twenty-nine        seven
```

I would like the center of each word lined up with one another.

What can I do to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first compute the maximum word length in the whole array and then use the [`:^{width}` format specifier](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) to center each word within that available width:

```
width = max(len(word) for line in arr for word in line)
for line in arr:
    print(' '.join(f'{word:^{width}}' for word in line), end='\n\n')
```

Comment: or before python 3.6: `print(' '.join('{:^{}}'.format(word,width) for word in line), end='\n\n')`